# CSS precedence link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get CSS precedence right but for some reason this code won't use the a:hover style defined in #hs properly. `#hs li.druid a:link` seems to overwrite the background-color defined in `#hs li a:hover` even though I'm just specifying a:link and not a:hover. It does inherit the other stuff like the color though. It doesn't matter where I place the code, I've tried switching it around but with the same result.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="hs">
    <li class="druid">
      <a href="druid">Druid</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#hs {  
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#hs li a:link, #hs li a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;  
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#hs li a:hover, #hs li a:active {
  color: #00AA00;
  background-color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#hs li.druid a:link {
  background-color: #855C33;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's due to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

The specifity of each selector:

- `#hs li.druid a:link` - 122
- `#hs li a:hover` - 112

You could decrease the specificity of the selector `#hs li.druid a:link`. Without the `id`, the specificity is lowered from 122 to 22.

```
li.druid a:link {
  background-color: #855C33;
}
```

---

A safer approach would be to increase the specificity of the selector `#hs li a:hover` by adding the id selector `#nav`. In doing so, you add 100 points to each selector, thereby allowing it to overwrite the other selectors.

```
#nav #hs li a:hover,
#nav #hs li a:active {
  color: #00AA00;
  background-color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is a relatively helpful link for [calculating specificity](http://specificity.keegan.st/) given a selector.

Comment: Nice online tool for that purpose - [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Comment: @Vucko Haha, literally just edited that into my answer when you submitted your comment. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't understand why a:link "overwrites" a:hover, I thought they were separate definitions. But I guess if you don't define any a:hover along with an a:link then it uses the data from a:link for a:hover as well.

Also isn't it kind of bad design to add the #nav bit since ids are supposed to be unique to a page, hence there would never be any need to specify an id along with a parent element like #nav.